# How to receive date from Receiver in Service?

Tags: android

I want to send date in Receiver and receive date in Service,but the Intent in Service has no date.blew is the code.Anyone know how to do? The requirement is simple,but it doesn't work as my wish...

//AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".AlarmService"/>
<activity android:name=".AlarmActivity"/>
```

//Receiver

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent musicService = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        intent.putExtra("requestCode",1024);
        context.startService(musicService);
    }
```

//Service

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int requestCode = intent.getIntExtra("requestCode", 0);
        Log.e("AlarmService", "onStartCommand: " + requestCode);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

// LOG

```
06-10 09:33:49.923 6498-6498/kingja.alarm.guider E/AlarmService: onStartCommand: 0
```